# session files not found in session save path

Tags: php, html

I was trying to use the following php script to specify my session save path:

```
<?php
echo session_save_path('/temp');
echo session_save_path();
?>
```

Line 2 was to set my save path to a directory called ‘/temp’.
Line 3 was to print out my current save path.  As I expected, it did print out ‘/temp’.
I then went to the temp directory to look for my session files but there is none.  Restarting Apache server didn’t help.  When I call phpinfo(), I can see session.save_path has no value.  Can anyone kindly and patiently tell me how I correctly set session_save_path and find my session files please?

Comment: verify that:  `is_writeable(ini_get("session.save_path"));`

Comment: `session_save_path` is a session setting so AFAIK it will never affect phpinfo. Secondly, to write anything in a session file you have to start a session first. Are you doing so?

Comment: I changed the php.ini file to "session.save_path="C:\temp", but the save path did not change to my desired location.  I ran "is_writeable(ini_get("session.save_path"))" and the returned is 1.  Does 1 mean writable or not writable?

Comment: it means that it's writable. On windows use "C:/temp" or "C:\\temp" however "C:/temp" is preferred.